# torch: minimally pad tensor such that num elements divisible by x

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I have a tensor `t` of arbitrary ndim
I want to pad (with zeroes) it such that
a) I introduce the fewest possible # elements
b) after padding, `(t.numel() % x) == 0`

Is there a better algorithm for doing this than
find the largest dimension and increase it by 1 until condition (b) is satisfied?

Maybe working code:

```
def pad_minimally(t, x):
    largest_dim = np.argmax(t.shape)
    buffer_shape = list(t.shape)
    new_t = t.clone()
    print(t.shape)
    for n_to_add in range(x):
        if new_t.numel() % x == 0:
            break
        buffer_shape[largest_dim] = n_to_add
        new_buffer = torch.zeros(*buffer_shape)
        new_t = torch.cat([t, new_buffer], axis=largest_dim)
    assert new_t.numel() % x == 0
    return new_t
assert pad_minimally(torch.rand(3,1), 7).shape == (7,1)
assert pad_minimally(torch.rand(3,2), 7).shape == (7,2)
assert pad_minimally(torch.rand(3,2, 6), 7).shape == (3,2,7)
```

Comment: The greedy approach you propose also doesn't always result in minimal padding. For example, if your original shape were `(3, 2)` and you wanted numel to be divisible by 9 then the minimal padding would be to make your tensor into a `(3, 3)` while your algorithm results in `(9, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, simply adding one to the largest dimension until `numel` is divisible by `x` doesn't work in all cases. For example if the shape of `t` is `(3, 2)` and `x = 9` then we would want to pad `t` to be `(3, 3)`, not `(9, 2)`.

Even more concerning is that there's no guarantee that only one dimension needs to be padded. For example if `t` has shape `(13, 17, 25)` and `x = 8` then the optimally padded `t` would be either `(14, 18, 26)` or `(13, 18, 28)`.

Distilling this into the mathematics, the problem becomes

> Given positive integers `s[1], ..., s[D]` find positive integers `q[1], ..., q[D]` that minimize `prod(q[i], i=1 to D)` subject to the constraints that `prod(q[i], i=1 to D)` is divisible by `x` and `q[i] >= s[i]` for all `i=1 to D`.

I wasn't able to develop an efficient solution (see update for more efficient solution), though I'm not particularly well versed in non-linear integer programming. Perhaps an efficient solution to this problem exists. If it does I imagine it would involve the prime factors of `x` and `q` and/or better memoization. That said, it is possible to solve the problem using an exhaustive search, provided that `x` and `D` (i.e. `len(t.shape)`) are sufficiently small (otherwise the algorithm may run for a really really long time).

The brute force search algorithm I came up with iterates over each multiple of `x` greater-than or equal to `t.numel()` and uses depth-first search to see if a padding exists for that multiple. As soon as a valid padding is found the algorithm finishes. The python code for this algorithm is:

```py
import numpy as np

def search(shape, target_numel, memory):
    numel = np.prod(shape)
    if numel == target_numel:
        return True
    elif numel < target_numel:
        for idx in range(len(shape)):
            shape[idx] += 1
            if tuple(shape) not in memory:
                if search(shape, target_numel, memory):
                    return True
                memory.add(tuple(s for s in shape))
            shape[idx] -= 1
    return False

def minimal_shape(shape, target_multiple):
    shape = [s for s in shape]
    target_numel = target_multiple * int(np.ceil(max(1, np.prod(shape)) / target_multiple))
    while not search(shape, target_numel, set()):
        target_numel += target_multiple
    return shape
```

Once you have the minimal shape, the `pad_minimal` function can be implemented pretty succinctly as

```py
def pad_minimally(t, x):
    new_shape = minimal_shape(t.shape, x)
    new_t = t.new_zeros(new_shape)
    new_t[[slice(0, s) for s in t.shape]] = t
    return new_t
```

I'm not sure if this will be fast enough for your needs. Hopefully someone else can come along with a more efficient version.

---

Some test cases for `minimal_shape`

```py
assert minimal_shape([2, 2], 9) == [3, 3]
assert minimal_shape([2, 8], 6) == [2, 9]
assert minimal_shape([13, 17, 25], 8) in [[14, 18, 26], [13, 18, 28]]
assert minimal_shape([5, 13, 19], 6) == [5, 14, 21]
```

---

#### Update

I [asked about this algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/135173/131615) on CS.SE. Based on the answer I received there and the subsequent update to the question the following is a much more efficient implementation of `minimal_shape`.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul
from copy import deepcopy

def prod(x):
    return reduce(mul, x, 1)

def argsort(x, reverse=False):
    return sorted(range(len(x)), key=lambda idx: x[idx], reverse=reverse)

def divisors(v):
    """ does not include 1 """
    d = {v} if v > 1 else set()
    for n in range(2, int(v**0.5) + 1):
        if v % n == 0:
            d.add(n)
            d.add(v // n)
    return d

def update_memory(b, c_rem, memory):
    tuple_m = tuple(b + [c_rem])
    if tuple_m in memory:
        return False
    memory.add(tuple_m)
    return True

def dfs(a, b, c, c_rem, memory, p_best=float('inf'), b_best=None):
    ab = [ai + bi for ai, bi in zip(a, b)]
    p = prod(ab)
    if p >= p_best:
        return p_best, b_best
    elif p % c == 0:
        return p, deepcopy(b)

    dc = divisors(c_rem)
    for i in argsort(ab):
        for d in dc:
            db = (d - ab[i]) % d
            b[i] += db
            if update_memory(b, c_rem // d, memory):
                p_best, b_best = dfs(a, b, c, c_rem // d, memory, p_best, b_best)
            b[i] -= db

    return p_best, b_best

def minimal_shape(shape, target_multiple):
    a = list(shape)
    b = [0 for _ in range(len(a))]
    c = target_multiple
    _, b = dfs(a, b, c, c, set())
    return [ai + bi for a, b in zip(a, b)]
```